# Difference on Project Folder size and amount of data Push on GIT

Tags: git

I am new using git and i noticed that on my last commit, it pushed 111.62 MB of data, when the project folder only contains a little less than 14 MB.

I Checked the repository and the files are the same, meaning there is no "left-over" files from previous commit or pushes. I commited everything before the push and had the following status:

`On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean`

The only thing i can think of is the control file for the repository that git creates when we call 
`$git init`

So the question is why the difference in the amount of Data between the Folder containing the project and the amount of data send to the repository once the push was made?

Comment: 111.62 Mo of data? What are you putting under version control? HD videos?

Comment: That's what i would like to know. So far i did not found a way to discover on what is in it. As mentioned on the post, the Project Folder only contains 14MB, mostly images.

Comment: Is the `.git` directory taken into account when you say "14MB"?

Comment: No, it is not. The folder was hidden so i did not notice it's existence. It seems the data comes from there. Upon further analysis, i have seen that the data is located in .git/objects/pack , on a .pack file. 

Is there anything that can be done to said file to make the size of the pushes smaller?

Comment: I think the pack file is a compressed file, and if you have several versions of the same file, it should compress pretty well. Maybe the data is pushed uncompressed? Also, not sure git is the best tool for versioning big files. You may want to have a look at git-lfs

Comment: I believe i know what happened. The original folder had indeed some very large files ( A lot of .psd files ). I realized that i forgot to delete them before pushing and canceled the operation mid-way so i could push once they were deleted. 

On the .pack file there must be some compressed .psd files that were compressed for the push.

Answer (score 0):

Just posting the answer here in case anyone happens to have the same issue.

Thanks to greg0ire in the comments of this post, i was able to recognize where the size was coming from. The bulk of the files were located inside the .git directory, more specifically on the .git/objects/pack directory, on a .pack file.

It happened because i did a push with some very large files added on the commit. I only realized it when the push was around 100 MB of data when i killed the command ( Ctrl + Z ). So part of the files were already in the local and remote repository when i killed the command mid-way of the push.

Because the project was at the start, the easiest solution was to create a new repository.